# Como puxo o dado já selecionado anteriormente no cadastro para um combobox na edição?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, combobox

Tenho um cadastro de cliente que é feito pelo usuário e depois disso tem a parte q o usuário pode editar essas informações. Estou tendo problemas para puxar dados já selecionados para o combobox de acordo com o que o usuário já havia cadastrado, como por exemplo, o estado.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="CadastrarCliente_<?= $result[$i]["cod"] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="CadastrarCliente_<?= $result[$i]["cod"] ?>" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-body">
<form method="post" action="api/cadastrarCliente.php">
<input type="number" name="codFuncionario" value="<?= $result[$i]["cod_funcionario"] ?>" style="display: none;">
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label>Cliente</label>
      <select name="pessoa_cliente" class="form-control maskField" id="pessoafouj" data-target-id="cpfOuCnpj" disabled>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-7">
      <label for="cpfOuCnpj">CPF/CNPJ</label>
      <input name="cpf_cnpj_cliente" type="text" id="cpf_cnpj_cliente" class="form-control" placeholder="CPF/CNPJ" disabled value="<?= $result[$i]['cpf_cnpj'] ?>" disabled>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-6" >
      <label for="inputNome">Nome</label>
      <input name="nome_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_cliente" placeholder="Nome/Nome Fantasia" disabled value="<?= $result[$i]['nome'] ?>" disabled>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputSobrenome">Sobrenome</label>
      <input name="sobrenome_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" id="sobrenome_cliente" placeholder="Sobrenome"  value="<?= $result[$i]['sobrenome'] ?>" disabled>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-7">
      <label for="rg_cliente">RG</label>
      <input name="rg_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" id="rg_cliente" placeholder="RG" disabled value="<?= $result[$i]['rg'] ?>" disabled>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-5" >
      <label for="inputSexo">Sexo</label>
      <select name="sexo_cliente" id="sexo_cliente" class="form-control" disabled>
         <option selected disabled="">Sexo</option>
         <?php 
            require_once "api/conexao.php";

            try {
                $prepared3 = $conexao_pdo->prepare("select * from sexo");
                $prepared3->execute();

                if ($result3 = $prepared3->fetchAll()) {
                    for ($i3=0; $i3 < sizeof($result3); $i3++) { 
                        echo "<option value='". $result3[$i3]["cod"] ."'>". $result3[$i3]["sexo"] ."</option>";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<option></option>";
                }
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "<option></option>";
            }   

            ?>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEndereço">Endereço</label>
      <input name="endereco_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" id="endereco_cliente" placeholder="Endereço" disabled value="<?= $result[$i]['endereco'] ?>" disabled>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputEstado">Estado</label>
      <select name="estado_cliente" id="estado_cliente" class="form-control" disabled>
         <option selected disabled>Estado*</option>
         <?php
            try {
                $prepared2 = $conexao_pdo->prepare("select * from estado");
                $prepared2->execute();

                if ($result2 = $prepared2->fetchAll()) {
                    for ($i2=0; $i2 < sizeof($result2); $i2++) { 
                        if ($result2[$i2]["cod"] == $result2[$i2]["estado"]) {
                            $selected = "selected";
                        }
                        else { $selected = "";
                    }
                    echo "<option ". $selected ." value='". $result2[$i2]["cod"] ."'>". $result2[$i2]["uf"] ."</option>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<option></option>";
            }
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "<option></option>";
            }   

            ?>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputNum">Número</label>
      <input name="numero_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" id="numero_cliente" placeholder="Número" disabled value="<?= $result[$i]['numero'] ?>" disabled>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputBairro">Bairro</label>
      <input name="bairro_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" id="bairro_cliente" placeholder="Bairro" disabled value="<?= $result[$i]['bairro'] ?>" disabled>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputCEP">CEP</label>
      <input name="cep_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" id="cep_cliente" placeholder="CEP" disabled value="<?= $result[$i]['cep'] ?>" disabled>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputComplemento">Complemento</label>
      <input name="complemento_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" id="complemento_cliente" placeholder="Complemento" disabled value="<?= $result[$i]['complemento'] ?>" disabled>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputCidade">Cidade</label>
      <input name="cidade_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" id="cidade_cliente" placeholder="Cidade" disabled value="<?= $result[$i]['cidade'] ?>" disabled>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputTelefone">Telefone</label>
      <input name="telefone_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" id="telefone_cliente" placeholder="Telefone"disabled value="<?= $result[$i]['telefone'] ?>" disabled>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail">E-mail</label>
      <input name="email_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" id="email_cliente" placeholder="E-mail" disabled value="<?= $result[$i]['email'] ?>" disabled>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tem que fazer requisições assíncronas dá uma pesquisada em AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente, não é muito recomendável utilizar o `for` para esse tipo de operação e sim o `foreach`. Um exemplo no primeiro select:

```
   <div class="form-group col-md-5" >
      <label for="inputSexo">Sexo</label>
      <select name="sexo_cliente" id="sexo_cliente" class="form-control" disabled>
         <option selected disabled="">Sexo</option>
         <?php 
            require_once "api/conexao.php";

            try {
                $prepared3 = $conexao_pdo->prepare("select * from sexo");
                $prepared3->execute();
                $result3 = $prepared3->fetchAll();

                    foreach($result3 as $resultado3) { 
                        echo "<option value='". $resultado3["cod"] ."'>". $resultado3["sexo"] ."</option>";
                    }

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "<option></option>";
            }   

            ?>
      </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: Oii, não funcionou :(